# Predict existing data using scikit learn

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

My dataset looks like this:

```
age      address   freetime  goout  Dalc   Walc   G1  G2    G3     AverageG
17       U         1         1      3      5      7   7     7      7
15       X         3         2      6      3      5   4     2      3.6666
20       T         1         5      4      1      3   2     1      2
```

What I'm trying to do using python is to predict the value AverageG which is the average of G1, G2, G3.

I know that the value of AverageG can be calculated by making the average of G1, G2 and G3 but in my case it has to be predicted by using the library scikit-learn

Comment: Hmmm, could you make it perhaps run a multiple linear regression on the values of G1, G2, and G3? I don't know scikit learn, but this may be what you are looking for. If so, I'm sure a Google Search might get you some results for implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

For this toy example you can use [linear regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html).

I will give the general idea, then you can translate it for your specific dataframe:

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np

X = np.random.randint(0,10,(1000,3))
y = X.mean(axis=1)

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, y)

new_data = np.array([1,2,3]).reshape(1, -1)
model.predict(new_data)
```

and the model correctly predicts:

```
array([2.])
```